# MySql Session from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I'll make a login session from 2 tables. if username and password match than make a operation join tables. than make a session from all field in join table. anyone know about that query?

I've been try but it not working:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE username='$username' && password='$password' && table1.FK = table2.PK)";
```

Comment: At a glance, You're wide open for an SQL injection. You should use parameterized queries using PDO.

Comment: And let's better not talk about the password...

Comment: oke Lion... thanks for suggestion... it's just prototype to know that query can be process or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping your `&&`s to `AND`s

If that doesn't work, could you let us know what the output actually is from your query?

Comment: still doesn't work. this is output: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
$match  = mysql_fetch_array($instr_di_query);

if ($match >= 1 ){ 
$_SESSION['a']=$match['a']; //a is field in table1
$_SESSION['b']=$match['b']; //b is field in table1
$_SESSION['c']=$match['c']; //c field in table2

Comment: That's the output from running your SQL query?

Comment: no... that is the next process... and if that run, output will be nothing, stiil in login page.

Comment: So what exactly are you asking? Is it that your SQL query isn't working, or that you don't know how to generate the query in the first place?

Comment: isn't working when i use 2 tables (with that join query) in session. i need the other variabel from tables2 for make that session.

Comment: I'm having problems understanding what you mean; you're trying to retrieve data from two tables, using the above query, but the query isn't working, is that right? In which case, could you paste into your question the error that the database is giving you when you run the query?

Comment: hehehe... i'm sory, i'm bad in english. this my complet code:

there is not a mesage error... i just can't login.

Comment: So are you generating the SQL query properly? Echo it out to the screen, and try cutting and pasting that directly into the database

Comment: solved after lunch... i don't know why that can be solved by JOIN LEFT... thank for your advice Andrewsi :)

Comment: @red - would you mind updating your question with the solution?

Comment: it's my friend query:
$sql="SELECT * FROM emp JOIN area ON area.cdarea = emp.cdarea WHERE (idemp='$username' && password='$password')";